# How to set Gmail "Basic HTML" as Default/Standard (for slow connections)?

Tags: gmail

I use "Basic HTML" very often for Gmail and I want have this as default.

My internet research told my it should be possible.

> To set the Basic HTML view as your default so that you don't need to select the link every time you sign in, click “Set Basic HTML as Default View” at the top of the Gmail account screen when you're using Basic HTML view.

I don't see a button “Set Basic HTML as Default View”

And [this page](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-gmail-display-mail-basic-html-44852.html) sounds hopeful, but I was not able to to this. Is this still possible and how?

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/1psomethindr/

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the banner either. Perhaps Google disabled this option, or it depends on your browser or account. I would advise to bookmark the dedicated link for Basic HTML: https://mail.google.com/mail/h/ - that will always take you to the basic version.

Answer (score 0):

When I click on either the dedicated link for basic HTML 
`https://mail.google.com/mail/h/`  
or the link in your question  
`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/1psomethindr/` 
I get the following screen.

[image: gmail header in basic HTML]

I see "Set Basic HTML as Default View".  When I do that, it remains in default view, although it continues to offer the switch to standard view if I want it, on each of my subsequent visits to Gmail.

Comment: with me this notice is not (firefox in kubuntu).

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I should have added that part to my answer. Using Google Chrome browser and Windows 10 0/S

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2Nr1Yyo with me this notice is not (firefox in kubuntu).